# miniMagick identify error in rails_admin app: Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, rails-admin, minimagick

I am using `carrierwave` and `mini_magick` gems to use images inside `rails_admin`. When I upload an image it fails with this error:

```
Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? 
Original Error: `identify C:/Users/Zeke/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20161027-21132-xdongz.png` failed with error: 
    identify.exe: RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/662. 
    identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

And this doesn't happen when I don't include the following lines in my `uploader.rb`

```
  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process resize_to_fit: [800, 600]

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [40, 30]
  end
```

**I require thumbnails, and how do I do it?**

---

> Here's What I'm sure of:

- *ImageMagick* has been installed and **is working** for sure. I *am* able to convert png to jpg and jpg to png, identify images...
- `identify C:/Users/Zeke/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20161027-21132-xdongz.png` executes successfully when run in `cmd` *(without admin priv, if that matters)*

[image]

- `identify -list format` gives a *huuuuge* list that almost contains every image format I can think of. And yes, it includes `JPG`, `JPEG`, `PNG` and all that I need.

[image]

- `convert -version` **does include** jpeg png *delegates*

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: currently using ruby `2.2.4-p230` and rails `5.0.0.1` on Win 10

Comment: Closely related http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26856, suggested solution doesn't work; tried adding three variables to path as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/452657/396728), but no use

Comment: I don't know ruby or rails, but I suspect you have ImageMagick installed more than once and are using a different ImageMagick (which can do PNG) at the command prompt whereas you are maybe using a different ImageMagick in rails which cannot do PNG. Try setting your PATH in rails to explicitly use the same ImageMagick as you use at the command prompt. Or try searching for another `convert` or `identify` throughout your system.

Comment: Or try temporarily renaming the `convert.exe` which works at the Command Prompt as `convert.orig` and then running Rails and seeing if it notices that or if it is using a different executable altogether.

Comment: i regret, there is **exactly** one installation of imageMagick and I installed it only now

Comment: Renaming's a good idea...! :) Just figured out rails didn't require convert; it got stuck at `identify` as the error desc says... and yeah, even tried it with `identify` - and no changes in error desc; is the same error thrown if identify is _not found_?

Comment: Oh man! holy ###, you're right; You nailed it......! There was another _passive_ installation of `imagemagick` inside of my ruby dir, and that is why renaming new files I installed now didn't affect the errors in any aspect...

Comment: Works like charm now, cleaned the dir and re-installed :) Saved my day! Just curious, you had this exact situation before?

Comment: No, I have never used Rails or Ruby. I just know that people often take several attempts to install ImageMagick and leave old, partially-installed versions lying around and often aren't entirely using the same version from the command line as they are from PHP, Ruby, Perl, CGI, C#.... anyway, glad it worked out for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `identify` and `convert` I tested were working fine except for the fact that *they* were not actually used by `rails`, which used another installation of `imagemagick` which was very old and threw this `translation missing` error at first which I managed to solve by adding a few lines in `en.yml`

> It is notable that ***System Environment Variables*** can be overridden by ***set path*** that only lasts long for that instance of `cmd`

Making rails use the new version of `ImageMagick` solved the problem.
***Credits**: Mark Setchell*